# TidTCPServer, how to write data without loosing characters

Tags: delphi, indy, tcpserver

I am using Delphi XE2 with latest Indy from SVN.

I am trying to send data to a socket using `AContext.Connection.Socket.Write(string)`. The data contains German characters like `äöüßÄÜ`.

When the string I send is longer than 530 bytes, some of the special characters are replaced with blanks. Some are not. When I shorten the string length to 530, all characters are working fine.

I tried to write the output in blocks of length 500, it works only when I do a `Sleep(1)` between each write.

I would really like to send the data with one `Write()` command. How can I do this?

This is the non-working code (encoding is set to `IndyTextEncoding(437)` in the `OnConnect` event):

```
sOut := 'jölhniönjhiouöinjhioö-jhnioönhoinhiuhbgnujnhb-öihn-öouhn'+
        'jölhniönjhiouöinjhioö-jhnioönhoinhiuhbgnujnhb-öihn-öouhn'+
        'jölhniönjhiouöinjhioö-jhnioönhoinhiuhbgnujnhb-öihn-öouhn'+
        'jölhniönjhiouöinjhioö-jhnioönhoinhiuhbgnujnhb-öihn-öouhn'+
        'jölhniönjhiouöinjhioö-jhnioönhoinhiuhbgnujnhb-öihn-öouhn'+
        'jölhniönjhiouöinjhioö-jhnioönhoinhiuhbgnujnhb-öihn-öouhn'+
        'jölhniönjhiouöinjhioö-jhnioönhoinhiuhbgnujnhb-öihn-öouhn'+
        'jölhniönjhiouöinjhioö-jhnioönhoinhiuhbgnujnhb-öihn-öouhn'+
        'jölhniönjhiouöinjhioö-jhnioönhoinhiuhbgnujnhb-öihn-öouhn'+
        'jölhniönjhiouöinjhioö-jhnioönhoinhiuhbgnujnhb-öihn-öouhn'+
        'jölhniönjhiouöinjhioö-jhnioönhoinhiuhbgnujnhb-öihn-öouhn';
//sout := leftstr(sout, 500);

AContext.Connection.Socket.Write(sOut);
```

Comment: Why are you using an old DOS-based codepage like 437 instead of a more appropriate modern codepage like 1250 or 1252, or even 28591 (ISO-8859-1/Latin-1) or 28605 (ISO-8859-15/Latin-15)? They would handle German better (especially 28605, which has full coverage of German, whereas 28591 has almost full coverage).

Comment: In any case, Indy has no inherent length restrictions on encoding strings. `TIdIOHandler.Write(string)` encodes the entire string to a `TIdBytes` (using `IdGlobal.ToBytes()`, which internally uses `IIdTextEncoding.GetByteCount()` and `IIdTextEncoding.GetBytes()`) and then writes the entire `TIdBytes` to the socket (using `TIdIOHandler.Write(TIdBytes)`). Please verify that `ToBytes()` is encoding the full string correctly. If it is not, there is likely a bug in the encoding process. That has nothing to do with how `TIdIOHandler` sends raw bytes over a socket.

Comment: Hi Remy, 

thanks very much for your answer.

when i try 

    myBytes := ToBytes(myString, IndyTextEncoding(28605));
    sOut := BytesToString(myBytes, IndyTextEncoding(28605));
 
it is working correct. 

but it is not working on the Socket. 


    AContext.Connection.iohandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding(28605);
    AContext.Connection.Socket.Write(myString, IndyTextEncoding(28605));
    
also not with other encodings.

Comment: There is no difference between you calling `ToBytes()` yourself vs `Write()` calling it for you. Your issue has to be related to code you haven't shown yet. The fact that you "fix" the problem with `Sleep()` is not an encoding problem but a communication problem. You can verify with a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, that the server is sending the correct bytes without the `Sleep()`.

Comment: What does the client code look like? The client is likely not reading the string correctly. Your server is not sending the encoded string's byte length to the client, so how does the client know when to stop reading? It can't (unless the length is encoded in the string itself). If it can't read the bytes correctly, it can't decode them properly. Please edit your question to show the client code that is trying to read the string.

Comment: Hi Remy, i just used telnet as client

Comment: Telnet is not a good test client for this situation. It has no concept of the encodings you are using, and will just display raw bytes as-is without actually decoding them. Also, most telnet clients are console apps, and console windows have their own share of problems when it comes to displaying encoded text. To validate your server, you need a test client that decodes what you are sending and displays it as intended.

Comment: HI Remy, thanks very much for your help :-)